# Counting consecutive values without interruption in pandas/Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on my pandas skills and have been stuck on an exercise for a while:

I have created a DF with bike test data. Tests are ordered by time (ascending test_id). I would like to get the most recent fail test (max `test_id`) for each `bike` + `test_type` group and count how many consecutive fails appeared in total (without interruption from a pass test for same group). Additionally, I would like to have another `ends_with_pass` column which tells us if a fail `bike` + `test_type` group is followed up by a pass test. How can I achieve this? I have the following code but don't know how to proceed:

```
fail = data[data["test_result"] == "fail"]
max_fail_tests = fail.groupby(["bike", "test_type"])["test_id"].max().reset_index()
res = pd.merge(max_failed_tests, data, on=["bike", "test_type"])

res["fails_in_a_row"] = res.groupby(
    ["bike", "test_type"]
)["test_result"].apply(
    lambda x: (
        x.eq("fail") & x.shift().ne("pass")
    ).cumsum()
)
```

Given input:

```
| test_id | bike | test_type | test_result |
|---------|------|-----------|-------------|
| 1       | a    | slow      | pass        |
| 1       | a    | fast      | pass        |
| 15      | c    | fast      | pass        |
| 15      | c    | slow      | pass        |
| 34      | b    | slow      | fail        | <-
| 34      | b    | fast      | fail        | <- 1st fail for b
| 36      | a    | slow      | pass        | 
| 36      | a    | fast      | pass        |
| 37      | c    | fast      | fail        | <- 
| 37      | c    | slow      | fail        | <- 1st fail for c
| 87      | c    | fast      | fail        | <- 
| 87      | c    | slow      | fail        | <- 2nd consecutive fail for c
| 99      | b    | slow      | fail        | <-
| 99      | b    | fast      | fail        | <- 2nd consecutive fail for b. Followed by pass, therefore `ends_with_pass` = `yes`
| 124     | b    | slow      | pass        |
| 124     | b    | fast      | pass        |
```

Expected output:

```
| bike | test_type | fails_in_a_row | ends_with_pass |
|------|-----------|----------------|----------------|
| b    | fast      | 2              | yes            |
| b    | slow      | 2              | yes            |
| c    | fast      | 2              | no             |
| c    | slow      | 2              | no             |
```

Comment: How exactly does the output reflect "get the most recent failed test (max test_id)" ? I don't see that in any say.

Comment: For a, no fail, so no max. For b, test_id 99 is max. So you count back from that point since it’s ordered over time (test_id is asc). For c, it is test_id 87, since there is no fail after that… Is that clear?

Comment: Once you have the max test_id for a bike+test_type, you basically keep counting past fails till you detect a pass. That is the `fails_in_a_row` column

Comment: If I understand correctly, if we added 10 fails for `bike=c` and `test_type=fast` with `test_id<15`, the expected output would not change. `fails_in_a_row` only counts the last (chronological) streak of fails.
Is that correct ?

Comment: That is correct! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an alternative approach:

```py
rows = []
for (bike, test_type), sdf in df.groupby(["bike", "test_type"]):
    fails = sdf["test_result"] == "fail"
    if not fails.any(): continue
    groups = ((sdf["test_result"] != sdf["test_result"].shift())
              .fillna(True).cumsum())
    fails_in_a_row = groups[groups == groups[fails].iat[-1]].shape[0]
    ends_with_pass = sdf["test_result"].iat[-1] == "pass"
    rows.append([bike, test_type, fails_in_a_row, ends_with_pass])
columns = ["bike", "test_type", "fails_in_a_row", "ends_with_pass"]
out = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=columns)
```

- Build sub-dataframes `sdf` by grouping over columns `bike` and `test_type`.
- Check for `"fail"`s: If none, skip the iteration.
- Determine the connected `groups` in column `test_result` (i.e. groups of consecutive identical values).
- Now `fails_in_a_row` is the length of last group that corresponds to a fail. And `ends_with_pass` depends on the last value in column `test_result` being equal to `"pass"`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my solution. I tried quite hard to make it more elegant and efficient but I couldn't really find a better way.

I added quite a bit to your sample dataframe since I kept thinking of new edge cases. One edge case that I'm sure I didn't account for is if the last 2+ tests for a `bike, test_type` are passes, the streak is considered to be 0 (not technically wrong, just depends on the formulation of the given task).

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
import numpy as np

raw = """ test_id  bike  test_type  test_result 
 1        a     slow       pass        
 1        a     fast       pass
 2        c     fast       fail
 2        c     slow       fail
 3        c     fast       fail
 3        c     slow       fail
 4        c     fast       fail
 4        c     slow       fail
 5        d     slow       fail
 5        d     fast       fail
 6        e     fast       pass
 6        e     slow       pass
 7        f     fast       fail
 7        f     slow       fail
 15       c     fast       pass
 15       c     slow       pass
 34       b     slow       fail        
 34       b     fast       fail        
 36       a     slow       pass        
 36       a     fast       pass        
 37       c     fast       fail        
 37       c     slow       fail        
 87       c     fast       fail        
 87       c     slow       fail
 88       f     fast      pass
 88       f     slow       pass
 99       b     slow       fail        
 99       b     fast       fail        
 124      b     slow       pass        
 124      b     fast       pass        
"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(raw), sep='\s+')
g = ['bike', 'test_type']
df = df.set_index(['bike', 'test_type', 'test_result', 'test_id'])

#get the last test for the group and its result
last_test = df.reset_index(level=(2,3)).groupby(level=[0,1]).last()
out = last_test.rename({'test_result':'last_test_result', 'test_id': 'last_test_id'}, axis=1)

#find the last passing test for the group (NaN if none exist)
last_pass = df.xs('pass', level=2).reset_index(level=2).groupby(level=(0,1)).last()
out = out.join(last_pass.rename({'test_id': 'last_pass_id'},axis=1))

#find the second to last passing test for the group (NaN if none exist)
second_to_last_pass = df.xs('pass', level=2).reset_index(level=2).groupby(level=(0,1)).nth(-2)
out = out.join(second_to_last_pass.rename({'test_id': 'second_to_last_pass_id'}, axis=1))

#find the last failing test for the group (NaN if none exist)
last_fail = df.xs('fail', level=2).reset_index(level=2).groupby(level=(0,1)).last()
out = out.join(last_fail.rename({'test_id': 'last_fail_id'},axis=1))

#dropping all rows groups which haven't had a fail
out = out[~out['last_fail_id'].isnull()]

#if last_pass_id is NaN then we need to count from the beginning to last_test_id
out['last_pass_id'] = out['last_pass_id'].replace(np.NaN, -1).astype(int)

#if second_to_last_pass is NaN then we need to count from the beginning to last_pass_id
out['second_to_last_pass_id'] = out['second_to_last_pass_id'].replace(np.NaN, -1).astype(int)

#if last test was a fail then the streak is between last_pass_id and last_fail_id
out.loc[out['last_test_result']=='fail', 'lower_bound'] =  out[out['last_test_result']=='fail']['last_pass_id']
#if last test was a pass then the streak is between second_to_last_pass_id and last_fail_id
out.loc[out['last_test_result']=='pass', 'lower_bound'] =  out[out['last_test_result']=='pass']['second_to_last_pass_id']
out = out.drop(['last_test_id'], axis=1)

df = df.reorder_levels(['test_id','bike', 'test_type','test_result']).sort_index()
def func(row, df=df):
    bike, test_type = row.name
    df = df.xs(bike, level=1).xs(test_type, level=1).xs('fail', level=1)
    streak = (df.index > row.lower_bound).sum()
    return streak

out['fails_in_a_row'] = out.apply(func, axis=1)
out['ends_with_pass'] = out['last_test_result']=='pass'
out = out.drop(['last_pass_id', 'second_to_last_pass_id', 'lower_bound', 'last_fail_id', 'last_test_result'], axis=1)
out
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def function1(dd:pd.DataFrame):
    col1=dd.test_result.ne("fail").cumsum()
    ss1=dd.assign(col1=col1).loc[dd.test_result.eq("fail")].col1.value_counts(ascending=False)
    ends_with_pass = 'yes' if ss1.size and (col1.eq(ss1.index[0])&col1.shift(-1).eq(ss1.index[0]+1)).any() else 'no'
    return dd.iloc[[0]].assign(fails_in_a_row=ss1.max(),ends_with_pass=ends_with_pass).drop(columns='test_result')

df1.groupby(['bike','test_type'],as_index=False,group_keys=False).apply(function1).query("fails_in_a_row>0")
```

：

| bike | test_type | fails_in_a_row | ends_with_pass |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| b | fast | 2 | yes |
| b | slow | 2 | yes |
| c | fast | 2 | no |
| c | slow | 2 | no |